# Why Size of folder not showing up in Finder?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, finder

In Below Image Size of each folder is not showing up, It shows --
[image]

**My Macbook - 13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports /MACOS 13.6 (22G120)**

I tried this but no luck -

Press Command + J or click View > Show View Options from the top menu bar. Check the box for Calculate all sizes.

Comment: How long did you give it? It can take quite a long time to do the initial calculation.

Comment: @Tetsujin ~4 min

Comment: Have you checked back since? Usually by the time it's worked it out the first time, subsequent toggles of that setting become almost instantaneous. That looks like an odd view of the folder, though. How do you have it set to get an 'under 100 bytes' header. I've never seen that before.